# How can i construct this three level hierarchy Query,

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario.

I have sql server table structure like below

```
ID          CodeLevel   ParentID    Name
    ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
    1           1           NULL        Company Group
    40          2           1           Corp Fun
    41          3           40          Fin
    45          4           41          Cont
    48          4           41          CFO
    51          4           41          Inv Rel
    52          4           41          CTandC
    94          3           40          COffice
    95          4           94          CEOffice
```

I'm looking for a query to get Business unit, Business Division and Business Group. Eg: CodeLevel = 4 are all Business Units.

Now, for ID = 95, Name is CEOfffice. CEOffice is BusinessUnit

For ID = 95, ParentID is 94. For ID=94, Name is COFfice which is Business Division

For ID=94, Its patentID is 40. So, ID=40, Name is Corp Fun which is BusinessGroup.

So, when ID = 51:

- BusinessUnit is Inv Rel
- BusinessDivision is Fin
- BusinessGroup is Corp Fun

Please help me in writing the query for this. Thanks

Comment: If it's always up to 3 levels and no more, you could use a from clause join to the same table 2 additional times and you'd have it.  If it can be more than 3 you need to look at using forxml path or a CTE to do the recursive query the hierarchy needs.  Show us what you've tried and we'll likely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just two joins

```
select base.ID, base.Name, div.Name, grp.Nave
  from table as base 
  join table as div 
    on div.ID = base.parentID
   and base.ID = 51
  join table as grp
    on grp.ID = div.parentID
```